# How do I do ssh "passwordless" login with raspberry pi?

Tags: ssh

I would like to disable passwords in `sshd` and use just keys.

```
root@igla:~# cat /etc/debian_version 
8.0
root@igla:~# uname -a
Linux igla.gotdns.ch 4.1.19+ #858 Tue Mar 15 15:52:03 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
root@igla:~#
```

How do I do it with my Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Linux (or OSX) computer to ssh into your Pi. You could use this to add your key to the authorized_host file on you Pi.
This requires that you already have generated your own ssh-keys on the client.
Otherwhise, run:

```
ssh-keygen
```

To add your client to Authorized host on your server, run:

```
ssh-copy-id [user]@pi
```

example:

```
ssh-copy-id root@192.168.2.31
```

Disable password authentication by editing this line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Answer (score 1):

After having setup SSH keys for authentication as mentioned in the first answer, you can disable password authentication (i.e. so that only logins with SSH keys work), by adding the line

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on (`Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords`)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ssh keys. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/
I don't think you can remove authentication.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also note that the OP was not asking to remove authenticiation but seems to be fine with keys.